# Q: How Do I Make A Collecting Coin For My Platform Game?

Tags: python, pygame

> > I have made a simple platformer game and I wanna learn how I can make a basic collecting coin system 
> >     where coins spawn on my platform and when I consume it I gain points with a point system
> >     here is my game so fare: [Game](https://gyazo.com/e479a7366ae521e494c65248e0e137a9) 
> >     I have looked on youtube how to do this but there isn't any tutorial that is covering it and I have found 1 but they aren't explaining how I could do it, it
> >     and my script:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
pygame.init()


# screen
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hyeo")
playerx = 350
playery = 250


# player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.speed = 5
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)

# enemy class
class enemys:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)


# FPS
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#  Colors
NiceBlue = (46, 196, 187)
NiceGreen = (48, 196, 46)

# define players by name
playerman = player(40,390,30,30, NiceBlue)
enemy1 = enemys(150,390,150,10, NiceGreen)
enemy2 = enemys(350,300,150,10, NiceGreen)
enemy3 = enemys(70,250,150,10, NiceGreen)
enemy4 = enemys(-1000,480,1900,60, NiceGreen)

# put them in a list so we can call all of them at the same time
enemies  = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4]

# Coins my g

# main Loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # Right and Left
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed

    # FOR DOWN AND UP
    if playerman.y > 450: #somewhere close to the bottom of the screen
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall  #reverse direction
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed

    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height +1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - player.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right
                break

        if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height


        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.4
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    window.fill((0,0,0))
    playerman.draw()
    enemy1.draw()
    enemy2.draw()
    enemy3.draw()
    enemy4.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: How about making a coin class where you display a coin on the platform. When the user collides with the coin just like it collides with the platforms. The coin disappears and it adds to the players coin counter variable

Comment: I can make a coin class and show it on my screen but idk how to make it dis-pear when it collides with the player and I want to display a scoring system when I touch the coin I gain a point I am new to python sorry

Comment: start by looking up how to make an object disappear. You could probably remove it from an array of coins and it would disappear from the screen. Then give the player class a score variable that goes up by however many whenever you remove the coin.  simplify it with class functions once you have it working. its all about trying to step away from the tutorials in the end. they can only get us so far

Comment: thanks for the tip but this problem I been trying to do for days lol

Answer (score 2):

like @GrahamOrmond said, create a coin class, in fact you could possibly use the same class but thats up to you, create a new list and create the coins just like the enemies. Loop through them and check for the `if playerman.rect.colliderect(coin.rect):` and if it collides, add 1 to the score and delete it from the list, you can use `del Coin_list[coin_index]` to delete the coin (coin index is where abouts in the list it is).

Give it a go first, show us what you tried, and we will help

---

Awesome, looks pretty good, only 2 problems i can see,

1) you need to move the coins with the scroll, this is easy, same as enemies but with coins, ill let you do this

2) for the collision, you are doing the same as enemies where if collide, move on top, which is not what you want, you want it to disappear and go through it

for the collision, there is kinda of a advanced technique you gotta use and that is to loop through the coins backwards

```py
for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(coin.rect):
        del Coins_list[i]
        score += 1
```

this is because when you delete something from a list, everything moves down one to fill it, e.g. if you delete the 3rd element, the 4th now becomes the 3rd. so if you are looping through all of them, and you delete the 3rd one, when you go to the 4th one, it is actually the 5th one as the 4th moves to 3rd. so you end up skipping one and you will get an index error for trying to get the last element which moved to one less. So backwards mean that if you delete one, the ones you already checked get moved and the ones you hvanet stay the same.

For the text, have a variable `score` (like above) and set it to 0. the text is hardcoded to 0, so you want it to be the score so it changed

```
score = 0
text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, NiceOlive)
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)
```

I also added this to the collision with the coins underneath `score+= 1`

now you may notice that the coins dont disappear, that is because you drawing them individual, you only want to draw them if they are in the list

```py
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()

    playerman.draw()
    for enemey in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
```

here is the full code

```py
import pygame
import random
import time 
pygame.init()



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------VV window screen size
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("DUDE RUFAIDA UGLY ASS HELL")
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# --------------------------------------------VV coins class
class coins:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, NiceOlive, self.rect)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# --------------------------------------VVV player class

# draw the player
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.speed = 5
        self.fall = 0
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------------VV enemy class

class enemys:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# --------------------------VV frames per sec
# FPS
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ---------VV colors

# COLORS
NiceYellow = (255,255,0)
NiceOlive = (0, 255, 0)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------VV define enemy and players xx,y,height and colors
# define enemy and player class
playerman = player(40,390,30,30, NiceOlive)
enemy1 = enemys(150,390,100,10, NiceYellow)
enemy2 = enemys(300,300,100,10, NiceYellow)
enemy3 = enemys(80,250,100,10, NiceYellow)
enemy4 = enemys(-5000,490,100000,100, NiceYellow)

enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4]
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# --------------------------define coins colors and width,heights anD coins LIST
coin1 = coins(250,250,20,20,NiceOlive)
coin2 = coins(350,350,20,20,NiceOlive)
coin3  = coins(300,300,20,20,NiceOlive)
coin4 = coins(150,150,20,20,NiceOlive)
coin5  = coins(50,390,20,20,NiceOlive)
Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3,coin4,coin5]   
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# -----------VV scoring 
# display scoring
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score = 0
text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, NiceOlive)
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
# -----------------------Draw the players and coins and enemys
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()

    playerman.draw()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# --------------------------# VV screen movements
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------VV player keys and screen movements
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed



    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ---------------------------collisions with player and enemy
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right
 # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ---------------------------------collision with coins and player     
        for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                del Coins_list[i]
                score += 1
                text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, NiceOlive)
                textRect = text.get_rect()  
                textRect.center = (100, 40)                
# ------------------------------- here is the problem I said if playerman.rect.colliderect coin1 it should then collide and delete the coin1 from coin list and then it should add it in to the score 1 point 


        if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: [Created a Class](https://gyazo.com/140b2703cd5aaacbe228c11d6ebc2d0a) [defined my coins and created a list](https://gyazo.com/5c97a50ed8c7fe4575a0dda78ae1e164) [Drawed my coins in the main Loop](https://gyazo.com/bac7070ba7cf1282c83ec77e337f1e79) [and did the collision](https://gyazo.com/5767f47dc13b8928384a5aa8467beefc) The problem is I am getting an error and and not sure if I did everything coreectly here is the full code: [Link](https://pastebin.com/xYtL8DFE)

Comment: I fixed the error displayed text on the screen THE ONLY PROBLEM is that when I collide with my coins it doesn't dis-pear and it doesn't add to my scoring here is the code: https://pastebin.com/raw/QzQ167ED I have described the parts in the code video [Link](https://gyazo.com/a4c798ff8283c80a435e07dd97304cc1)

Comment: thanks SO much I tried my best and you helped me out THANK YOU!!

Comment: @HabibIsmail No problem, if you give it a go first then get stuck, you can learn it for next time instead of copy and paste code. :)

Comment: I am not a fan of copying and pasting a code I would write the whole thing myself thank you! copying and pasting wont help me learn anything